# CSS properties in textarea in the Customizer

Tags: css, theme-customizer, code, esc-textarea

I am trying to create a custom field (text/CSS code in textarea) that include the CSS suggestion like Additional CSS in the customizer:
https://i.postimg.cc/9QhLPgVk/image.png.

Does everybody has experience with that?

I need any solution like the above screenshot here: https://i.postimg.cc/L55cpChD/image.png.

Comment: It uses CodeMirror, see examples in https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/10/22/code-editing-improvements-in-wordpress-4-9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, I was literally just doing some stuff with the customizer.

You can use the following class to get what you need..

```
WP_Customize_Code_Editor_Control
```

I'll include it in the control ready to go.

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Code_Editor_Control( $wp_customize, 'favorite_html', array(
        'label' => 'Theme CSS',
        'description' => '',
        'code_type' => 'text/css',
        'section' => 'section_id',
        'settings' => 'settings_control'
    )));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Steve, I missed `WP_Customize_Code_Editor_Control` on my own code. I appreciate it.